# BIGQUERY - Query to find all UUID's which are having unique SSN and DOB values from joining 2 tables based on UUID column

Tags: google-bigquery

Let's say there are 2 tables.

Table 1 : match
Table 2 : normalized

MATCH TABLE : COLUMN NAME : UUID

NORMALIZED TABLE : COLUMN NAMES : UUID, SSN, DOB

In MATCH table there is a column "UUID" and in NORMALIZED table there are columns 'UUID', SSN and DOB. After joining these two tables, need to fetch the uuid which are having unique SSN and DOB

Need to fetch the matched UUIDs records on the below tables by joining 2 tables

MATCH TABLE : UUID Column

| Record # | uuid |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123456789 |
| 2 | 123456789 |
| 3 | 123456789 |
| 4 | 123456789 |
| 5 | 998764556 |
| 6 | 112233445 |

NORMALIZED TABLE : UUID, SSN, DOB columns

| Record # | uuid | ssn | dob | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123456789 | 54321 | 03/08/1986 | SSN is repeated in record #3 |
| 2 | 123456789 | 98765 | 03/08/1986 | DOB is repeated in record #1 |
| 3 | 123456789 | 54321 | 03/08/1986 | SSN is repeated in record #1 |
| 4 | 123456789 | 77654 | 10/10/2000 | SSN is repeated in record #5 |
| 5 | 998764556 | 77654 | 11/11/1960 | SSN is repeated in record #4 |
| 6 | 112233445 | 66546 | 07/14/1970 | SSN and DOB is unique |

OUTPUT : Need to display "All UUID's which have SSN and DOB are unique".

| Record # | uuid |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 112233445 |

This record should display in the output as this UUID has both SSN and DOB are unique from the table.

I have tried with the below queries:

Scenario 1 : Find all UUIDs with Unique SSN

QUERY : select * from MATCH_TABLE where UUID in (select DISTINCT UUID from NORMALIZED_TABLE A,MATCH_TABLE B where A.uuid=B.uuid and A.SSN is not null AND A.SSN in (SELECT C.SSN from NORMALIZED_TABLE C GROUP BY C.SSN having count(1)<2)

Scenario 2 : Find all UUIDs with Unique DOB

QUERY: select * from MATCH_TABLE where UUID in (select DISTINCT UUID from NORMALIZED_TABLE A,MATCH_TABLE B where A.uuid=B.uuid and A.DOB is not null AND A.DOB in (SELECT C.DOB from NORMALIZED_TABLE C GROUP BY C.DOB having count(1)<2)

Scenario 3 : Find all UUIDs with Unique SSN and DOB.

QUERY: select * from MATCH where UUID in (select distinct a.uuid from NORMALIZED a,MATCH b where a.uuid=b.uuid and a.ssn is not null and a.dob is not null and CONCAT(a.ssn,a.dob) in (select concat(c.ssn,c.dob) from NORMALIZED c group by c.ssn,c.dob having count(1)<2))

I'm not getting the correct output. Can anyone please help me with the query.

Comment: Could you also provide an input example?

Comment: @SergeyGeron, the above table is the input example, sorry for the confusion. I have updated the table description with Input and Output.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be

```
select * from (
  select as value any_value(t) from `project.dataset.table` t 
  group by ssn having count(1) = 1
) intersect distinct 
select * from (
  select as value any_value(t) from `project.dataset.table` t 
  group by dob having count(1) = 1
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the Query, When I applied on my original table I used this query select * from (
  select as value any_value(t) from `project.dataset.table` t 
  group by SSN having count(1) = 1) intersect distinct 
select * from ( select as value any_value(t) from `project.dataset.table` t 
  group by BIRTH_DATE having count(1) = 1)   I got zero records. In the query should i give any SSN value or BIRTH_DATE value in "value any_value(t)". Can you please help me..

Comment: I haved added the detail example in the original question. Can you please correct me where I'm doing wrong and please correct the queries if i did any mistakes,please

Answer (score 0):

Try windowed `count(*) over(partition by column_name)`:

```
with mytable as (
  select 1 as record, 123456789 as uuid, 54321 as ssn, '03/08/1986' as dob union all
  select 2, 123456789, 98765, '03/08/1986' union all
  select 3, 123456789, 54321, '03/08/1986' union all
  select 4, 123456789, 77654, '10/10/2000' union all
  select 5, 998764556, 77654, '11/11/1960' union all
  select 6, 112233445, 66546, '07/14/1970'
)
select *
from (
  select 
    *,
    count(*) over (partition by ssn) as ssn_count,
    count(*) over (partition by dob) as dob_count
  from mytable
)
where ssn_count = 1 and dob_count = 1
```

[image]

Comment: When i applied the logic which provided in my original table, it gave zero records as output. It means there are no unique records with the combination of SSN and DOB?? SELECT * FROM(SELECT *,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY SSN)AS SSN_COUNT,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY BIRTH_DATE)AS BIRTH_DATE_COUNT FROM TABLE_NAME) WHERE SSN_COUNT=1 AND BIRTH_DATE=1 Can you please correct if my query is in correct.

Comment: Yes, no unique records. Query looks good.

Comment: If i need to join with another table (savvy_match). How should i do it?? The common column in both the tables is UUID, How can i achieve it? I have written the join query  select * from MATCH where UUID in (select distinct a.uuid from NORMALIZED a,MATCH b where a.uuid=b.uuid and a.ssn is not null and a.dob is not null and CONCAT(a.ssn,a.dob) in (select concat(c.ssn,c.dob) from NORMALIZED c group by c.ssn,c.dob having count(1)<2)). Is this query Correct?? As it is not giving the correct output.

Comment: Not sure if I follow... Could you provide an example of input data for all tables and expected output?

Comment: Sorry, really hard to understand. Could you provide input examples in a table format (like in your original question)? Add it to your original question or maybe create a new question, so that others would be able to help too.

Comment: I haved added the detail example in the original question. Can you please correct me where I'm doing wrong and please correct the queries if i did any mistakes,please.

Comment: Sorry, can't understand why we need to join with another table. It seems that NORMALIZED table is enough to produce the expected output. Better ask a new question with input examples of all tables and the expected output.

Comment: Good example of example input data and expected output: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67215138/join-number-of-pairs-in-a-single-table-using-sql

Comment: I have posted new question, can you help me to achieve this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67225639/big-query-fetch-the-uuids-from-match-table-which-are-having-unique-ssn-and-un