# Join number of pairs in a single table using SQL

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I have two tables of events in bigquery that look like as follows. The main idea is two count the number of events in each table (are always pairs of event_id and user_id) and join them in a single table that for each pair in any table it tells the number of events.

table 1:

```
| event_id | user id |
| -------- | ------- |
| 1        | 1       |
| 2        | 1       |
| 2        | 3       |
| 2        | 5       |
| 1        | 1       |
| 4        | 7       |
```

table 2:

```
| event_id | user id |
| -------- | ------- |
| 1        | 1       |
| 3        | 1       |
| 2        | 3       |
```

I would like to get a table which has the number of events of each table:

```
| event_id | user id | num_events_table1 | num_events_table2 |
| -------- | ------- | ----------------- | ----------------- |
| 1        | 1       | 2                 | 1                 |
| 2        | 1       | 1                 | 0                 |
| 2        | 3       | 1                 | 1                 |
| 2        | 5       | 1                 | 0                 |
| 4        | 7       | 1                 | 0                 |
| 3        | 1       | 0                 | 1                 |
```

Any idea of how to do this with sql? I have tried this:

```
SELECT i1, e1, num_viewed, num_displayed FROM
(SELECT id as i1, event as e1, count(*) as num_viewed
FROM table_1
group by id, event) a
full outer JOIN (SELECT id as i2, event as e2, count(*) as num_displayed
FROM table_2
group by id, event) b
on a.i1 = b.i2 and a.e1 = b.e2
```

This is not getting exactly what I want. I amb getting i1 which are null and e1 that are null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below

```
#standardSQL
with `project.dataset.table1` as (
  select 1 event_id, 1 user_id union all
  select 2, 1 union all
  select 2, 3 union all
  select 2, 5 union all
  select 1, 1 union all
  select 4, 7 
), `project.dataset.table2` as (
  select 1 event_id, 1 user_id union all
  select 3, 1 union all
  select 2, 3 
)    
select event_id, user_id,
  countif(source = 1) as num_events_table1,
  countif(source = 2) as num_events_table2
from (
  select 1 source, * from `project.dataset.table1`
  union all 
  select 2, * from `project.dataset.table2`
)
group by event_id, user_id
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Hello Mikhail, I am getting the error `Column name source is ambiguous at [2:11]`. Do you know why is not getting the source?

Comment: first - try to make sure you use query in my answer as it is - secondly, and this is less likely - in your real table - you might have `source` column already in your tables. so try to change `source` in my answer to `flag` for example

Comment: Thank you I finally got your idea and is working perfectly, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the simplest method is to modify your query via a `USING` clause along with `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT id, event, COALESCE(num_viewed, 0), COALESCE(num_displayed, 0)
FROM (SELECT id, event, count(*) as num_viewed
      FROM table_1
      GROUP BY id, event
     ) t1 FULL JOIN
     (SELECT id , event, COUNT(*) as num_displayed
      FROM table_2
      GROUP BY id, event
     ) t2
     USING (id, event);
```

Note:  This requires that the two columns used for the `JOIN` have the same name.  If this is not the case, then you might still need column aliases in the subqueries.

Comment: Hello Gordon, thank you for the help. This is almost what I was looking for, but the problem is what if an event is only in the second table.I am not getting any id - event which the num_viewed is 0. Do you know how to solve this? Thank you again :)

Comment: @rgralma . . . This code will return all `id`/`event` combinations that are in both or either table.  Perhaps your actual query is different from this.

Answer (score 0):

One way is aggregate the union

```
select event_id, user id, sum(cnt1) cnt1, sum(cnt2) cnt2
from (
    select event_id, user id, 1 cnt1, 0 cnt2
    from table_1
    union all
    select event_id, user id, 0 cnt1, 1 cnt2
    from table_2 ) t
group by event_id, user id
```